# Cannot find referenced MovieClip in this.parent.insertMovieClip();

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, symbols, movieclip

Forgive me if there is an extremely simple answer to this question.

I am currently updating a series of .fla files that **someone else created**.  Within one of the symbols is the following code:  `this.insertMovieClip("symbolName","objectReferenceName",5);`

I understand what the code is doing, or rather what it would do **normally**.  It would find a symbol named `symbolName` in the library, and create an instance of it named `objectReferenceName` inside `this` MovieClip.

The problem is that I have searched the library, and I can't find anything named `symbolName`.  It doesn't exist.  But somehow, there is a movie clip being called at runtime - the code works.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this AS2 or AS3? What your describing sounds like AS2 but your tag for your question says AS3.

Comment: Very sorry.  I clicked the wrong tag; it is AS2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol names in the library actually have no effect at run-time—they are simply labels. The identifier that gets used at run-time is set in the Linkage properties for a symbol. You can see this by looking under the AS Linkage column in the library, or right-clicking a symbol and clicking Properties.

In AS2, you assign an identifier to a symbol by checking the "Export for ActionScript" box in the Properties dialog. You can then create an instance of that symbol from ActionScript like this:

```
attachMovieClip("linkageIdentifier", "reference", depth);
```

This is probably what your `insertMovieClip` function is doing.

Comment: Thank you!  You are right, I was looking at the symbol name, not the identifier.